# How to pass specific array index as input in a module in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, multiplexing

I have a 4:1 Mux as follows:

```
module mux4_1 (input [31:0]A, input [31:0]B, input [31:0]C, input [31:0]D, input sel[1:0], output [31:0]Y);

wire mux1o, mux2o;
mux2_1 mux1 (A, B, sel[0], mux1o);
mux2_1 mux2 (C, D, sel[0], mux2o);
mux2_1 mux3 (mux1o, mux2o, sel[1], Y);

endmodule
```

In another module I have an array `F` of length 4 as input and need an instance of the 4:1 mux in this module with elements `F[1]` and `F[3]` of `F` as selectors. How can I specifiy this when declaring the instance? Surely this code below does not work, but it should illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

```
module someModule (inputs... F[3:0], outputs...);
 // some code...
 mux mux4_1 (A, B, C, D, F[1]F[3], Y);
endmodule
```

Comment: `{F[1],F[3]}` but make sure you got the order the right way around. Normally the select goes MS to LS: `{F[3] , F[1]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create you selector signal, you can simply concatenate the signal you need from your array.

```
wire [1:0] selector;
assign selector = {F[1], F[3]};

// selector is a 2 bit vector where 
// selector[0] == F[3]
// selector[1] == F[1]
```

A faster implementation would be in your case:

```
module someModule (inputs... F[3:0], outputs...);
     // some code...
     mux4_1 myInstance (A, B, C, D, {F[1], F[3]} , Y);
endmodule
```

In this case, the LSB of the selector is F[3] and its MSB is F[1]